# Copy a file with Python but not overwrite the file if it's already exists in target directory

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I'm having an issue figuring out how can i implement a function to overcome my problem.

My code works fine, but the fault is that sometimes i need more than just one file.

```
import os
import shutil


target_dir = 'C:\DIST\WR_4.5\Test'
pass_text = 'Test End'

def check_and_copy():
log = open('C:\DIST\WR_4.5\oHistory2.log')
for line in log:
    if pass_text in line:
        name = '\kp.log'
    else:
        name = '\kf.log'
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.makedirs(target_dir)
    shutil.copy2('C:\DIST\WR_4.5\oHistory2.log', target_dir+name)
else:
    os.chdir(target_dir)
    shutil.copy2('C:\DIST\WR_4.5\oHistory2.log', target_dir+name)
```

What i'd like to accomplish is to be able to copy multiple instances of files with or without shutil. The filename is determined by the code itself as you can see.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the `'x'`flag to `open` - this should try to create the file, but raise `FileExistsError` if it already exists: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open

Comment: i need multiple instances of the same file. 
e.g.: 
- kp.log
- kp2.log
- kp3.log
So what i need is a method so i can copy my source file in the same directory multiple times without overwriting the first one.